# How can I connect a component that holds the state and a presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to connect 2 different components.
One component holds the state and the other is the presentational component.
I want to show the products for each category to the CategoryContainer. But I need to have the categoryId in the ProductsList to show the products and set the correct values to the appropriate properties of some components(like TextBox, Dropdown). Any Ideas?

Component that holds state:

```
render() {
    const {
      categoryId,
      categoryName
    } = this.props;
    return (
        <MainComponent>
                <label>Your categoryId is: </label>
                {categoryId}
              <label>Your categoryName is: </label>
                {categoryName}
              <label>The products of this category are: </label>
            <div>
              <ProductLists />
            </div>
          </MainComponent>
  };
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    categoryName:
      selectAttributelById(state, ownProps.categoryId) &&
      selectAttributelById(state, ownProps.categoryId).get("categoryName")
  };
};

CategoryContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(toJS(CategoryContainer));

CategoryContainerWrapped.propTypes = {
  categoryName: PropTypes.bool
};

export default CategoryContainer;
```

Presentational Component:

```
class ProductLists extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <TextBox/>
      <DropDownList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ProductLists.propTypes = {
};

export default ProductLists;
```

Comment: Why can't you just pass them as `props`?

Comment: they are shown as undefined

Comment: In your example nothing is passed as `props` to the `ProductList` component and no props are accessed from `ProductList`, therefore from your example, `undefined` is no option.

Comment: how can I pass the categoryId as props to the ProductList?

Comment: @AndreiOlar I already have the categoryId as I used React-Route and map it to the CategoryContainer . But how can I pass as props to the ProductsList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to read more about react and how to pass values as props between your components.

Secondly in your render function you need to pass the values as props to your ProductList component.

```
render() {
    const {
      categoryId,
      categoryName
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <MainComponent>
            <label>Your categoryId is: </label>
            {categoryId}

            <label>Your categoryName is: </label>
            {categoryName}

            <label>The products of this category are: </label>

            <div>
                <ProductLists categoryId={categoryId} categoryName={categoryName} />
            </div>
        </MainComponent>
     );
  };
}
```

Lastly in order to see the categoryId and categotyName in you ProductList you just need to display them.

```
class ProductLists extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                CategoryId: {this.props.categoryId}
                CategoryName: {this.props.categoryName}
               <TextBox/>
               <DropDownList />
           </div>
        );
    }
}

ProductLists.propTypes = {
    categoryId: PropTypes.number,
    categoryName: PropTypes.string
};

export default ProductLists;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I did the same. The only diff is that I did a console.log to shown the categoryId which printed undefined when it was with a string text. I dont want to show them. I need to pass them as parameters like this <TextBoxcategoryId={categoryId} />

Comment: It cannot be undefined, only if they come as undefined from the redux store directly in the component from which they are passed further.